# Use JavaScript variable in JSON for API

Tags: javascript, json, api, mandrill

this code can be used for the Mandrill API for sending mails from a website. But the problem is I can't get the HTML input into the JSON to send to the correct email address. Look at the code beneath:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/js/mandrill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="send-email.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="e-mail" id="maila"/>
    <button onclick="sendTheMail(); return false;">Send the Mail</button>
    <pre id="response"></pre>
</body>
```

So this is the HTML and in the input field you type the mail address to whom you'd like to send.

Then I have the following .js file:

```
function log(obj) {
    $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('API-KEY');

var mailaddress = document.getElementById("maila").value;

var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email":"from@email.com",
        "to":[{"email":"to@email.com"}],
        "subject": "Sending you a mail",
        "html": "Text for the body of the mail",
    }
};

function sendTheMail() {

    m.messages.send(params, function(res) {
        log(res);
    }, function(err) {
        log(err);
    });
}
```

So here I get the var mailaddress which is the mail address to which I would like to send a message and which the user has given in the browser. But now I want the value "to@email.com" to take the variable of var mailaddress. But just entering this variable here doesn't work as I think it's not JSON...

I know the program works, because if I fill in a mail address in the "to":[{"email":"to@email.com"}], manually it will send and arrive. Tried to search the forum and google but could not find a solution for this..

**UPDATE**
I got it, thanks for the help. The getElementById has to be within a function I think, so I moved the code a little bit... It looks like beneath. The code is working now, but I am curious: is this nice coding or do I have to orden things?

```
function log(obj) {
    $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('API-KEY');


function sendTheMail() {
// Send the email!
var mailaddress = document.getElementById("maila").value,
recipient = [{"email": String(mailaddress)}];
var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email":"email@gmail.com",
        "to": recipient,
        "subject": "Sending a text email from the Mandrill API",
        "text": "I'm learning the Mandrill API at Codecademy.",
        "autotext": true
    }
};
    m.messages.send(params, function(res) {
        log(res);
    }, function(err) {
        log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  mailaddress = document.getElementById("maila").value,
  recipients = [],
  recipient = { "email": mailaddress };

recipients.push(recipient);

var params = {
  "message": {
    "from_email": "from@email.com",
    "to": recipients,
    "subject": "Sending you a mail",
    "html": "Text for the body of the mail",
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems that this code is not working. If I fill in the 'to' manually the program works.. For example: "to":[{"email":"email@gmail.com"}]. Is there a problem with the structure (not being JSON?) or somewhere else in the code you think? Without variable customization (not HTML input) the program works as mentioned before..

Comment: I don't see why it should not work. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see either.. that's the whole problem... Get these error: {"status":"error","code":-1,"name":"ValidationError","message":"You must specify a message value"} as soon as I insert this code snippet into the program: var mailaddress = document.getElementById("maila").value,
recipients = [],
recipient = { "email": mailaddress };

recipients.push(recipient); really strange...

Comment: When I remove the .value it works again in a way that it does not raise an error. But then it doesn't take the value from the input field.. Then the result says: [{"email":null,"status":"invalid","_id":"API-KEY","reject_reason":null}], so then it doesn't take a input for email.. Don't know what is wrong.. When I use the codecademy editor it also says this: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("maila").value')

Comment: see the update in the post, got it working, thank you! is this clean code?

Comment: The code looks fine, could use some indetation you know. Sorry i didn't saw the real problem. When you have the `mailaddress = document.getElementById("maila").value,` outside the function, the script retrieves the content from the input on page load, when its empty. Of course it has to get it when `sendTheMail()` is called. I implicitly fixed that unknowingly in my answer, but didn't realize :)

Comment: Ah no, its to much to say i fixed the problem in my answer. My code was ment to go in `sendTheMail()` but i didn't mention that.

Comment: thanks anyway ;-), the problem is solved, that's what matters!